# redirect https www to https non www in iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

```
    <rule name="rd" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test\.com$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.\test\.net$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://test.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

this code work when for example:

```
 http://www.test.com => https://test.com

 http://www.test.net=> https://test.com
```

but not working when urls is:

```
https://www.test.com => https://test.com

https://www.test.net => https://test.com
```

what's problem?!

thanks fot helping

Comment: Why would it work if one of your conditions is `<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />`?

Comment: When the url is already using HTTPS, the entire rule would simply not apply

Comment: i wrote mistake,edited post

Answer (score 0):

I know you've said you want to do this in IIS, but if you can edit the Global.asax file in the application, you can do it this way.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        #if !DEBUG
        string HTTPhost = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];

        string domainName = "test";

        //assuming that the app will only be reached via .COM or .NET
        string topLevel = HTTPhost.Split('.').LastOrDefault();

        //compare to make sure it only matches the root name with no trailing subdomain
        //or to redirect to secure url if unsecured
        if ( (!HTTPhost.Split('.').FirstOrDefault().Equals(domainName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) )
         || (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection))
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent(
              "https://"
              + domainName
              + '.'
              + topLevel
              + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
            //RawUrl means any url information after the domain
        }
       #endif
}
```